# Matlab how to change contourf plot's location on z axis

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, z-axis

I have a 3d surface in my figure `surf(x,y,z)`

I also have a `contourf` surface (which is basically a 2D plane).

I plot them in the same figure but the `contourf` plot is automatically at `z=0` level. I want to move the `contourf` plot to `z=-10` (or any value on z-axis) but I can't do it.

I am sure it is easy but I can't find the answer in MATLAB help/Google.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
%# plot surface and contour
Z = peaks;
surf(Z), hold on
[~,h] = contourf(Z);       %# get handle to contourgroup object

%# change the ZData property of the inner patches
hh = get(h,'Children');    %# get handles to patch objects
for i=1:numel(hh)
    zdata = ones(size( get(hh(i),'XData') ));
    set(hh(i), 'ZData',-10*zdata)
end
```

[image: screenshot]

---

## UPDATE:

The above doesn't work anymore in HG2. It can be fixed using a hidden property of contours `ContourZLevel`:

```
Z = peaks;
surf(Z), hold on
[~,h] = contourf(Z);
h.ContourZLevel = -10;
```

You can also use [`hgtransform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgtransform.html) to achieve a similar thing, which is the documented and recommended approach.

See another answer of mine for further explanation: [plot multiple 2d contour plots in one 3d figure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24624311/97160).

Comment: if you hate loops, you can rewrite the last part in one-line: `set(hh, {'ZData'}, cellfun(@(x) -10*ones(size(x)), get(hh,{'XData'}), 'UniformOutput',false))`

Comment: excellent. thanks a lot. I just have to learn more about objects and how to use get and set to "inspect" and "change" stuff to my liking. do you know any good reference/tutorial other than Matlab Help ?

Comment: @Amro nice one. This will come in handy for sure.