# plot multiple 2d contour plots in one 3d figure [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour

I would like to know how to plot multiple,  2D contour plots spaced apart in the z-axis, in a 3D figure like this:

[image: blah]

Comment: The command you are probably looking for is [contourslice](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourslice.html). See documentation for further reference.

Comment: @CitizenInsane: that function is intended for visualizing volume data, I don't think the OP means to do that here.

Comment: @Amro Humm maybe was to easy to think data are volume-data. Your solution is nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **NOTE**: The first part of this answer was meant for HG1 graphics. See the second part if you're working with MATLAB R2014b and up ([HG2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html)).

---

## HG1:

The [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) function internally creates a number of [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) objects, and returns them as a combined [hggroup object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourgroupproperties.html). So we could set the `ZData` of all patches by shifting in the Z-dimensions to the desired level (by default contour is shown at z=0).

Here is an example:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
surf(X, Y, Z), hold on       % plot surface

[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20);   % plot contour at the bottom
set_contour_z_level(h, -9)
[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20);   % plot contour at the top
set_contour_z_level(h, +9)

hold off
view(3); axis vis3d; grid on
```

[image: multiple_contour_plots]

Here is the code for the `set_contour_z_level` function used above:

```
function set_contour_z_level(h, zlevel)
    % check that we got the correct kind of graphics handle
    assert(isa(handle(h), 'specgraph.contourgroup'), ...
        'Expecting a handle returned by contour/contour3');
    assert(isscalar(zlevel));

    % handle encapsulates a bunch of child patch objects
    % with ZData set to empty matrix
    hh = get(h, 'Children');
    for i=1:numel(hh)
        ZData = get(hh(i), 'XData');   % get matrix shape
        ZData(:) = zlevel;             % fill it with constant Z value
        set(hh(i), 'ZData',ZData);     % update patch
    end
end
```

---

## HG2:

The above solution doesn't work anymore starting with R2014b. In HG2, [contour objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html) no longer have any graphic objects as children ([Why Is the Children Property Empty for Some Objects?](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-is-the-children-property-empty-for-some-objects.html)).

Fortunately there is an easy fix, with a *hidden* property of contours called `ContourZLevel`.
You can learn more *undocumented* customizations of contours plots [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-contour-plots) and [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-contour-plots-part-2).

So the previous example simply becomes:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
surf(X, Y, Z), hold on       % plot surface

[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20);   % plot contour at the bottom
h.ContourZLevel = -9;
[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20);   % plot contour at the top
h.ContourZLevel = +9;

hold off
view(3); axis vis3d; grid on
```

[image: contours]

---

Another solution that works in all versions would be to "parent" the contour to a [`hgtransform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgtransform.html) object, and transform that using a simple [z-translation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/makehgtform.html). Something like this:

```
t = hgtransform('Parent',gca);
[~,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20, 'Parent',t);
set(t, 'Matrix',makehgtform('translate',[0 0 9]));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the type of figure which I wanted to plot.

Is there a way to adjust the spacing/viewing angle such that the contours do not overlap? (I am plotting 3 levels of contours, like the diagram, however each of the contours overlap with each other with the current perspective)

Comment: you can [interactively rotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/rotate-3d-interactive-rotation-of-3-d-views.html) the view in 3D, or do it programmatically with [`view(az,el)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html): http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/setting-the-viewpoint-with-azimuth-and-elevation.html. You can also [control the camera](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/view-control-with-the-camera-toolbar.html) for greater flexibility

Comment: I've updated the answer to show solutions for both HG1 and HG2