# Matlab - Contour plot with labeled levels over Surf plot

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, label

I would like to plot a `contour` or `contour3` with labeled levels over a `surf` plot with the same data using Matlab R2015b. Finally the figure is shown from above (the view in negative z-direction) to see the result.

My problem: The labels seem to disappear in the `surf` area - the product lacks the intended information.

My current test-code with the best result so far:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
v = -6:2:8;
hold on
surf(X,Y,Z)
shading interp
contour3(X,Y,Z,v,'k--','ShowText','on')
hold off
colormap default
caxis([-7,9])
view(0,90)
```

I am not yet allowed to post a picture of the result ..

Related questions in my consideration would be [how to change contourf plots location on z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054966/matlab-how-to-change-contourf-plots-location-on-z-axis) or [shift the z-value of contour plot in Matlab 2014b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204011/shift-the-z-value-of-contour-plot-in-matlab-2014b) to change the z-axis-property of a normal `contour` plot but they were no solution to my problem or did not work at all.

Comment: Have you tried `clabel` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clabel.html instead of the `'ShowText'` property?

Comment: thanks for your hint - `clabel` adds the option to label only selected levels but the problem with the partially disappearing numbers remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood your problem, you can solve it by doing all in 2D like so

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
v = -6:2:8;
hold on
contourf(x,y,z,500,'LineStyle','none');
[C,h]=contour(x,y,z,v,'k--');
clabel(C,h,'FontSize',15);
caxis([-7,9])
view(0,90)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot, that solves my problem :) it is hard do describe without a picture ..