# Plotting the x-y plane projection of a 3d plot (Wigner function) along with the 3d plot in a single figure

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, contour

I want a plot as the following:

[image: Wigner plot]

Here, the Wigner function calculated from the x,y data is plotted as `W` and its projection on the x-y plane is also shown.
I have used the following code that plots the Wigner function. How to show the projection of `W` on the x-y plane in the same plot?

```
xvec = [-2:2]; 
yvec = xvec;
W = wfunc(psi,xvec,yvec,g);
f1 = figure(1); 
mesh(xvec,yvec,real(W));
shading interp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hold on` to add many graphical objects in the same figure. For example:

```
figure    
surf(xvec,yvec,real(W),'linestyle','none')
hold on
contourf(xvec,yvec,real(W),100,'linestyle','none')
```

You can shift the `z`-position of the contour colormap (following to the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204011/shift-the-z-value-of-contour-plot-in-matlab-2014b)) using

```
[~,hc] = contourf(xvec,yvec,real(W),100,'linestyle','none');
hcpatches = findobj(hc,'Type','Patch');
for n=1:length(hcpatches)
  set(hcpatches(n),'ZData',-5*ones(size(get(hcpatches(n),'XData'))))
end
```

Also, you can try to use `surfc`.