# Matlab - Scale Colorbar of Image

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, axes, colorbar

How can I scale the `colorbar` axis of a false color image?

I read this post,and copied the code but it seems not to work correctly:

[MATLAB Colorbar - Same colors, scaled values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285114/matlab-colorbar-same-colors-scaled-values)

Please see the two images below. In the first (without the scaling) the coloraxis goes

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]*10^4
```

In the second image, it goes

```
[0.005 0.01 0.015 0.02 0.025]
```

The correct scaling (with `C = 100000`) would be

```
[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
```

Without scaling
[image: without scaling]

Wrong scaling
[image: wrong scaling]

I want that the coloraxis is scaled by `1/C` and I can freely choose `C`, so that when the pixel value = `10^4` and `C=10^6` the scale should show `10^-2`.

---

The reason why I multiply my image first by `C` is to get more decimals places, because all values below 1 will be displayed as zero without the `C` scaling.

When I run the code I get `yticks` as a workspace variable with the following values:

```
[500 1000 1500 2000 2500]
```

---

My code:

```
RGB = imread('IMG_0043.tif');% Read Image 
info = imfinfo('IMG_0043.CR2'); % get Metadata
C = 1000000; % Constant to adjust image

x = info.DigitalCamera; % get EXIF
t = getfield(x, 'ExposureTime');% save ExposureTime
f = getfield(x, 'FNumber'); % save FNumber
S = getfield(x, 'ISOSpeedRatings');% save ISOSpeedRatings
date = getfield(x,'DateTimeOriginal');
I = rgb2gray(RGB); % convert Image to greyscale
K = 480; % Kamerakonstante(muss experimentel eavaluiert werden) 
% N_s = K*(t*S)/power(f,2))*L 
L = power(f,2)/(K*t*S)*C; %
J = immultiply(I,L); % multiply each value with constant , so the Image is Calibrated to cd/m^2 

hFig = figure('Name','False Color Luminance Map', 'ToolBar','none','MenuBar','none');
% Create/initialize default colormap of jet.
cmap = jet(16); % or 256, 64, 32 or whatever.
% Now make lowest values show up as black.
cmap(1,:) = 0;
% Now make highest values show up as white.
cmap(end,:) = 1;

imshow(J,'Colormap',cmap) % show Image in false color
colorbar % add colorbar

h = colorbar; % define colorbar as variable

y_Scl = (1/C);
yticks = get(gca,'YTick');

set(h,'YTickLabel',sprintfc('%g', [yticks.*y_Scl]))

ylabel(h, 'cd/m^2')% add unit label
title(date); % Show date in image
caxis auto % set axis to auto
datacursormode on % enable datacursor

img = getframe(gcf);
nowstr = datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd_HH_MM_SS');

folder = 'C:\Users\Taiko\Desktop\FalseColor\';
ImageFiles = dir( fullfile(folder, '*.jpg') );
if isempty(ImageFiles)
    next_idx = 1;
else
    lastfile = ImageFiles(end).name;
    [~, basename, ~] = fileparts(lastfile);
    file_number_str = regexp('(?<=.*_)\d+$', basename, 'match' );  
    last_idx = str2double(file_number_str);
    next_idx = last_idx + 1;
end

newfilename = fullfile( folder, sprintf('%s_%04d.jpg', nowstr, next_idx) );

imwrite(img.cdata, newfilename);
```

Comment: are you looking for `caxis`?

Comment: well i am new to matlab and i just began to write this code. i tried it with and without the      caxis auto but it doesn't make a difference. i think it is really weird that it generated the y ticks as     [500 1000 1500 2000 2500] and i don't understand why.

Comment: i uploaded test image files here:  https://www.sendspace.com/file/1v5z48

Comment: For the love of any superior being, DO NOT USE JET FOR THIS

Comment: @Yvon Read (and watch) here: https://bids.github.io/colormap/ .In short: it is perceptually non-uniform. The same change in data would change the color from dark blue to almost light blue , or in a different place from yellow to orange to red. It shows (to the human eye) peaks and data change rates that are not in the data. It is also incredibly non-realistic when used in images. Just choose `parula` or `hot` and plot the same data, looks way more natural

Comment: @Yvon Steve from Mathworks also did a couple of posts about why jet is not default anymore, see this and the next post: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/10/13/a-new-colormap-for-matlab-part-1-introduction/

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: i changed the colormap to parula

Comment: @TaikoGreen great choice! I put the python colormaps to MATLAB if you are interested, here you can find them: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

1) You are getting `YTick` of the figure (`gca`) but not the color bar. That would give you the "pixel" coordinates of the graph, instead of the actual values. Use `yticks = get(h,'YTick');`.

2) `caxis auto` Should come before overwriting `YTicks` (and after enabling the color bar); otherwise the scale and ticks will mismatch.

3) Do you mean `C = 100000`?

Result:

[image]

Comment: C=10^6 would be appropriate for this image so that i can get the nightsky resolved(which will be the main purpose of this script) but it can also be used to measure the brightness of a facade. in this case you would choose a smaller C

Comment: @TaikoGreen That would result in different tick values. Is that as expected?

Comment: that is correct the picture you attached is with C=10^5, while the image i have attached is with 10^6. with you correction it shows now the correct tick values 0.01 to 0.06